# HTML input Search bar is not focusable when clicked by mouse but can only focus by TAB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

The Search bar is not focusable when clicked by mouse but can only focus by TAB

The script i got it form here [CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/rohanashik/pen/mpjemo)

The input search bar i used is given below

```
<input class="searchbar" id="searchbar" name="search" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Find a name for your idea"/>
```

I'm using this js scripts in the headers

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery‌​.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.mi‌​n.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zkhrhwpagv1cxqg/jqu‌​ery.hammer.js"></scr‌​ipt>
```

I'm using this Javascript, which i think this is the problem maker!
I'm using scroll hijacking.
The only problem maker is this javascript given below.
If I removed this js It works perfect.
Please someone help me solve this behavior.

```js
function l(o) {
  console.log(o)
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sections = $('.box').toArray();

  var scroll = {
    activeSection: 0,
    sectionCount: sections.length - 1,
    isThrottled: false,
    throttleDuration: 1000,
    target: $(sections[0]).position().top
  }



  function setSizes() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

      $(sections[i]).css({
        'top': window.innerHeight * i,
        'height': window.innerHeight,
        'width': window.innerWidth
      });
    }
  }

  setSizes();
  $('body').on('resize', setSizes());

  function downSection() {
    var positionFromTop = $(sections[scroll.activeSection + 1]).position().top;
    $("body, html").animate({
      "scrollTop": positionFromTop
    }, 300);
    ++scroll.activeSection;
  }

  function upSection() {
    var positionFromTop = $(sections[scroll.activeSection - 1]).position().top;
    $("body, html").animate({
      "scrollTop": positionFromTop
    }, 300);
    --scroll.activeSection;
  }

  $("body").hammer({
    preventDefault: true
  }).on("swipe", function(event) {
    if (event.gesture.direction == 'up') {
      if (scroll.activeSection != sections.length - 1) {
        downSection();
        l('SWIPED UP');
      }
    } else if (event.gesture.direction == 'down') {
      if (scroll.activeSection != 0) {
        upSection();
        l('SWIPED DOWN');
      }
    }
  });

  $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(window).on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (scroll.isThrottled) {
      return;
    }
    scroll.isThrottled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      scroll.isThrottled = false;
    }, scroll.throttleDuration);

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {

      if (scroll.activeSection === 0) return false;
      upSection();
      l('WHEELED DOWN');

    } else {

      if (scroll.activeSection >= scroll.sectionCount) return false;
      downSection();
      l('WHEELED UP');

    }
  });


  $(window).keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 40 && (scroll.activeSection != sections.length - 1)) {

      downSection();
      l('ARROW DOWN');

    } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && (scroll.activeSection != 0)) {

      upSection();
      l('ARROW UP');

    }

  });



}); // end doc ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="searchbar" id="searchbar" name="search" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Find a name for your idea" />
```

Comment: Please fix the console errors shown in the snippet I made for you - it seems you need some HTML with class="box"

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zkhrhwpagv1cxqg/jquery.hammer.js"></script>` I added this as a header but when i used ur edited code it works but the scroll hijacking stops working. And I dont have any classes related to class="box"

Comment: Update the question!!!

Comment: hey I've been updated please help me